# Graph conditional mean - r

Tags: r

Here's my dataset:

```
ID  A B  Y Time
1   1 0  1 1
1   1 0  4 2
...
1   1 0  7 10
2   1 1  3 1
...
```

Where A and B are dichotomous (doesn't change within the ID), Y is continuous and Time goes from 1 through 10 for every ID.

I'm trying to graph four lines (in the same graph):

Y when A=0 and B=0, Y when A=0 and B=1, Y when A=1 and B=0, Y when A=1 and B=1

with the X axis being the Time.

I  have calculated the mean Y when A=0, B=0, T=1, then Y when A=0, B=0, T=2 ... but it's not very efficient.

What would be the best way to graph the four lines?

Comment: Won't there be multiple`Y` values associated with a single point in `Time`, even given the `A` and `B` constraints?

Comment: Yes. The graphed value would be the mean of the Y for T

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one way using `aggregate` and `ggplot2`:

#### generate data

```
set.seed(123)
df1 <- data.frame(ID = rep(c(1:5), each = 10),
                  A = rep(c(0,0,1,1,0), each = 10),
                  B = rep(c(0,1,0,1,1), each = 10),
                  Y = rnorm(50),
                  Time = rep(1:10, 5))
```

#### use `aggregate`

```
df1_agg <- aggregate(Y ~ Time + A + B, data = df1, mean)
#add AB column
df1_agg$AB <- paste('A =', df1_agg$A, 'B =', df1_agg$B)

head(df1_agg) #what does it look like?
  Time A B           Y          AB
1    1 0 0 -0.56047565 A = 0 B = 0
2    2 0 0 -0.23017749 A = 0 B = 0
3    3 0 0  1.55870831 A = 0 B = 0
4    4 0 0  0.07050839 A = 0 B = 0
5    5 0 0  0.12928774 A = 0 B = 0
6    6 0 0  1.71506499 A = 0 B = 0
```

#### use `ggplot2`

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(data = df1_agg, aes(x = Time, y = Y, colour = AB))+
    geom_line()
```

[image]